# Primefaces widgetVar interfering with ui:repeat or ui:datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<ui:repeat>` that iterates over a `List<String>` and creates a `<p:commandButton>` with the value of the current String in a `<p:lightBox>`.
But when I add `widgetVar` to my `<p:lightBox>`'s attributes the value of the `<p:commandButton>` is always the String from the last iteration.

Can someone explain what happens and (as I need `widgetVar`) maybe point out a solution?

This is my html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <ui:repeat var="thing" value="#{bugBean.things}">
        <p:lightBox widgetVar="whatever">
            <h:outputLink>
                <h:outputText value="#{thing}" />
            </h:outputLink>
            <f:facet name="inline">
                <h:form>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{bugBean.writeThing(thing)}"
                            value="#{thing}" />
                </h:form>
            </f:facet>
        </p:lightBox>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is the backing bean:

```
package huhu.main.managebean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BugBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   List<String> things = new ArrayList<String>();

   public BugBean(){
      things.add("First");
      things.add("Second");
      things.add("Third");
   }

   public void writeThing(String thing){
      System.out.println(thing);
   }

   public List<String> getThings() {
      return things;
   }

   public void setThings(List<String> things) {
      this.things = things;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `widgetVar` basically generates a window scoped JavaScript variable. What you're effectively doing now in JavaScript context is:

```
window['whatever'] = new Widget(lightboxElement1);
window['whatever'] = new Widget(lightboxElement2);
window['whatever'] = new Widget(lightboxElement3);
// ...
```

This way the `whatever` variable in JS would only refer the last one.

You should basically be giving them each an unique name, for example by adding the iteration index:

```
<ui:repeat var="thing" value="#{bugBean.things}" varStatus="iteration">
    <p:lightBox widgetVar="whatever#{iteration.index}">
```

This way it becomes effectively:

```
window['whatever0'] = new Widget(lightboxElement1);
window['whatever1'] = new Widget(lightboxElement2);
window['whatever2'] = new Widget(lightboxElement3);
// ...
```

This way you can refer the individual lightboxes by `whatever0`, `whatever1`, `whatever2`, etc.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: isn't it easier to use a single lightbox and update its content on every click instead?

Comment: Great! Thanks for your enlightening answer and questioning my design. ;) Of course it's a lot more efficient to have just one lightbox that's content is updated. I will do it like that. I was irritated by the fact that the links opening the lightbox are already inside the lightbox-tags - now I realise that's not an obstacle. One more question: Where can I (re-)read what you just pointed out to me regarding my question?

Comment: You're welcome. I just observed the generated HTML code (which I already knew from top of head in this particular case by just looking at the JSF code).

Answer (score 0):

recently i had a similar problem when upgrading to primefaces 4.0 -> 5.1

I had to use syntax:

```
PF('whatever0')
```

Due to changes in how primefaces names the widgetvar.