# p:autocomplete itemSelect and change ajax events incosistency, solution without widgetVar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

Greetings to the community, I am trying to put both `itemSelect` and `change` events into `<p:autocomplete>` component in order to also **let the user input free text in the field apart from only selecting a specific value suggested by the autocomplete panel**.

Unfortunately both events cause a common incosistency for which a workaround has been proposed in many threads like [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=16677) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618684/primefaces-autocomplete-itemselect-versus-change-events) which is solved by introducing into the autocomplete element a `widgetVar` which will be used as a selector **to not trigger** the `change` **event while the autocomplete panel is visible**, which works great.

Unfortunately, introducing a `widgetVar` in my autocomplete element causes problem (autocomplete component is inside a `<p:tree>` component where multiple autocomplete elements can be created and lead to strange behaviour (sometimes while typing in an autocomplete element I see another autocomplete element gets triggered, while this does not happen when no widgetVar is put in the autocomplete element).

For instance, as shown in the image below, w**hile I am typing in the first autocomplete, the second one gets triggered**.

[image: while I am typing in the first autocomplete, the second one gets triggered]

What could be a workaround to solve this issue? A **way to get control over the component without a widgetVar** in order to use the `<p:ajax event="change" onstart="if(PF('<widgetVarName>').panel.is(':visible')) {return false;}"`  would be great! Any suggestions?

**PrimeFaces version: 7.0**

Comment: Do they both have different widgetVar names?

Comment: Hello Selaron, the autocomplete is inside a `<p:tree>` so each new element generated should have a different name, I also tried to put this `widgetVar=widgetVar="widgetVarName#{nodeVar.data.name}"` where `nodeVar.data.name` is `unique`, but still no luck :/

Comment: Just so that in a case the nodeVar.data.name are the same, please do not follow up till I re-test the solution :)

Comment: Ok, the problem indeed was the fact that in some cases the `widgetVarName#{nodeVar.data.name}` was under some conditions same, creating unique widgetVars to take control over specific components solved my issue so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199595/primefaces-widgetvar-interfering-with-uirepeat-or-uidatatable solves my problem :). Thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to accept this dupplicate (tbh. I don't know how to technically do this) so the question get's marked as such.